# Newline is being printed as a whitespace in Text Area of html. How do I resolve

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my small jquery script where I append data that I receive.

```
$.get('HelloWorld', {'data' : data}, function(newLogs) {
    $('#logsid').append(newLogs);
    $('#logsid').scrollTop($('#logsid')[0].scrollHeight);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, HTML renders newlines as spaces (and multiple whitespace is collapsed to one space). Add this rule to your stylesheet to preserve whitespace...

```
#logsid {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Or you can do this in jQuery...

```
$('#logsid').css("white-space", "pre");
```

You can also achieve this by changing `logsid` to be a `<pre>` element.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying this in eclipse. Still doesn't work there. It works fine on chrome though.