# HTML displays spans differently because of a whitespace newline

Tags: html, css

Why would

```
<div id='dD' class='cs'>
    <p class='c cB'>
        <span>X</span>
        <span>X</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

display like this

[image]

in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari

but this

```
<div id='dD' class='cs'>
    <p class='c cB'>
        <span>X</span><span>X</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

displays like this

[image]

I wouldn't expect a whitespace newline to have any impact on the way HTML is rendered.

I can rectify this by applying

```
display: block;
```

or

```
display: inline-block;
```

to the spans (not sure which is the better choice)

but don't understand why the browsers render differently because of a whitespace newline.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that whitespace is not the issue. Can you recreate the two scenarios you've shown, in a snippet or jsfiddle?  There's a good chance that you have some other CSS in your code inadvertently causing this effect.

Comment: I literally only cut out the white space between </span>
        <span>

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131815/newline-is-being-printed-as-a-whitespace-in-text-area-of-html-how-do-i-resolve, do browsers really treat newlines as spaces?! That can have potentially dramatic effects. May need to review all of my html.

Comment: Oops, meant 'display: block;', not 'display: inline;' in my question. Fixed

Comment: @GRW - for the initial value of `white-space`, which is `normal`, then yes newlines are converted to spaces at render time. Details are at https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#line-break-transform

Comment: ... It would help if you gave us a jsfiddle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the default behavior is to treat new lines as spaces.

That one space was enough to wrap the text beyond the width and render on separate lines.

Removing the newline removed the space so the Xs get rendered on the same line.

Adding

```
.c span {
    display: block;
}
```

forces each X to be treated as a block and rendered on separate lines, which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.cB {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I do want the text to wrap so nowrap would not be my solution.

Comment: That does work if I have <span>XX</span>, but I specifically want each X in it's own <span>, and it doesn't work for that situation

Comment: That does work, but I think I prefer my 'display: block;' solution since the separate spans are distinct entities that really should be separate blocks, not just text to break. Learned some things from your solutions and may come in handy some day, thanks.